# Oracle Invalid Column on simple count query

Tags: java, oracle, jdbctemplate

Currently trying to get a very simple query to run using **jdbctemplate** against an oracle db, running into the following error:

> PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL; Invalid
>   column type; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column
>   type

**Columns**

```
SYSTEM_UNIQUE_ID   VARCHAR2(50 CHAR)
SYSTEM_TYPE_ID      NUMBER(4,0)
```

**Call**

```
public int getSystemUniqueIDCount(final String systemUniqueID, final String systemTypeID) throws SQLException {

    String checkCountQuery = "select count(*) as count from master_account where system_unique_id = ? and system_type_id = ?";

    Map<String, Object> row = getTemplate().queryForMap(checkCountQuery , new PreparedStatementSetter() {

        @Override
        public void setValues(PreparedStatement pstmt) throws SQLException {
            pstmt.setString(1, systemUniqueID.toUpperCase());
            pstmt.setInt(2, Integer.parseInt(systemTypeID));
        }

    });

    return (int) row.getOrDefault("count", 0);
}
```

Any help would be much appriciated.

Comment: Isn't that trying to use the `PrepardStatementSetter` [as an argument](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#queryForMap-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-)? (Not something I've used, but I can't match what you're doing with the docs - I may be missing something obvious though!)

Comment: I agree with Alex and I don't see how your current snippet compiles and hence how you could see a runtime `SQLException` with what you've shared. Would you want to use `queryForMap()` or perhaps just [`query()`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#query-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object:A-org.springframework.jdbc.core.ResultSetExtractor-)?

Comment: @AlexPoole after rereading the docs you can use PreparedStatementSetter as an argument in query() which ive used extensively, but not in queryformap() which would be where my problem lies.  As to why it compiles? Apparently PreparedStatementSetter counts as a valid object array, albeit one that does not actually provide any value whatsoever.  I've switched to query() and things are now working as intended.  thanks to both you and Mick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

queryForMap() does not take a PreparedStatementSetter() as an argument, and instead in my case was assuming it was an object[] instead.  This meant that it was trying to insert the value of the preparedstatementsetter itself as a parameter in the query, which obviously blows up.

Thanks to Mike Mnemonic and Alex Poole.